# Is there a way to filter Yammer exported messages other than since/until

Tags: yammer

I'm using the Export API to get messages that i want to crawl intro SharePoint. I'm not sure if the documentation at https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api is up to date and i'm curious if there is a way to filter these messages by other means. For example: return a max number of messages, ignore private conversations, use pagination...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for data export is up to date. There isn't a way to do what you are seeking against that api.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @manetsus- Good point - here is the documentation on this feature. https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api